# Unix - Find and Sort by part of filename

Tags: sorting, unix, terminal, find

I have this:

```
D-T4-0.txt 
A-2.txt 
C-3-1.txt 
B-X1-3.txt 
E-2-4.txt
```

and I wish to order as follows:

```
D, C, A, B, E
```

I need to look at the last number in each (before .txt) `D-0, C-1, A-2, B-3, E-4`.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a pipeline like this:

```
# List files
ls |

# Include the sorting key in the front as well
sed -E 's/^(.*)([0-9]+)\.txt$/\2\t\1\2.txt/' |

# Sort on the sorting key
sort -n |

# Remove the sorting key
cut -f2-

# Grab the first letter
cut -c1
```

Output:

```
D                                                                                                           
C
A
B
E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `awk -F- '{print $NF}' file_name |sort`;do grep -- -$i file_name;done
```

- here I am extracting last field using awk delimited by - and sorting
- and using loop to grep on the sorted lines by adding - in front.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There's an erroneous semicolon after `do` :)

Comment: With awk I can sort, but I need to return the filename (the command "ls" is that it tells me the filenames)
How can I do it?

Comment: @rsa something like  **for i in `ls |awk -F- '{print $NF}'|sort`;do ls |grep -- -$i ;done**

Comment: in my batch, for does not work
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'